# Как настроить отправной адрес в компоненте joomla chronoforms?

Tags: joomla

Есть сайт организации, который работает на  **joomla 3**.  Для валидации форм настроил компонент **chronoforms5** и создал форму. Посетитель сайта может зайти на страничку, заполнить форму, после чего она отправляется на email организации, который указал в настройках компонента. Но есть проблема, не получается настроить адрес от кого отправляется письмо, когда письмо приходит на почту то там написано root@localhost, как поменять этот параметр на другое название? [Ссылка](http://joxi.ru/KAxdJgMsWwoDA8) на скрин. 
В настройках формы я указываю в разделе **Setup ->Email** ссылка -joxi.ru/bmo6JBbF6lgjry) в поле From name название организации (ссылка - joxi.ru/12M75Vxh38PGrJ) но root@localhost все равно сохраняется.